# How can I print this query result on my show.blade.php?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

How can I print the result of this query on my show.blade.php? This is what I did on my Controller:

```
public function getRating(Request $request){
            $results = DB::select('SELECT AVG(stars) FROM reviews WHERE stars>1', [1])->get();
        }
```

And this is what I tried on my show.blade.php

```
<li class="nav-item">
     <form action="{{ action('CatalogController@getRating')}}" method="GET">
       <div>
         {{$results}}
       </div>
     </form>
</li>
```

I'm still learning and I looked for this before making this question but I don't know if I couldn't find it or if I wasn't searching for the right thing, thanks.

Comment: search for `blade foreach`. Also, return the `results` on the method.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this, perhaps?

**RatingsController:**

```
use DB; // Make sure you call this above the class

public function returnAverageStars()
{
    $results = DB::table('reviews')->where('stars', '>=', 1)->avg('stars');

    return $results;
}

public function show()
{
    return view('show', [
        'reviews' => $this->returnAverageStars()
    ]);
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/show', 'RatingsController@show');
```

**show.blade.php**

```
<ul>
    <li>{{ $reviews }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

in your controller

```
public function getRating()
{
    $results = DB::select('SELECT AVG(stars) FROM reviews WHERE stars>1', [1])->get();

    return view('show', ['results' => $results]);
}
```

you should pass variable to view 
see this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#defining-controllers)